# How to remove space between number and sign in OutlinedTextField in Material Ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using material Ui OutlinedTextField here is my code snippet from the TSX file

```
import { List, styled, Switch, TextField, Theme, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

export const OutlinedTextField = withStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& label': {
      color: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    },
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
      '&.MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
        paddingRight: 0,
      },
      '&.MuiOutlinedInput-adornedStart': {
        paddingLeft: 5,
      },
    },
  },
}))(TextField);
```

Other.tsx:-

```
<OutlinedTextField
        variant="outlined"
        id="outlined-basic"
        type="number"
        size="small"
        value={parseFloat(Volatility.toFixed(2))}
        onChange={(event) => setVolatility(parseFloat(event.target.value))}
        onKeyPress={(event) => onKeyPressVolatility(event.key)}
        InputProps={{
          className: classes.inputText,
          endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">%</InputAdornment>,
        }}
      />
```

I want to remove space between number and % sign from the OutlinedTextField
Your suggestions would be helpful
Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: OutlinedTextField is a styled component? Where did it come from?

Comment: It come from `import { OutlinedTextField } from '../../commons/custom-material-components'; `  @hotcakedev

Comment: Can you post the component as well?

Comment: Ok I added it in my Question

Comment: Seems like my answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to set `text-align: right` for the input element inside `MuiOutlinedInput-root` class name.

Not sure where the `OutlinedTextField` component come from, but you can do like the following.

```
...
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const OutlinedTextField = styled(OutlinedInput)(() => ({
  '& input': {
    textAlign: 'right'
    ...
  }
}))
```

[image]

You can do the same if you use [makeStyles hook](https://mui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook).